# display the pdf in the same window

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, internet-explorer-11, pdf.js

there is a requirement where i have to show the pdf in the same window (may be inside the embed/object/iframe).
i am getting the pdf from the service in array buffer format, when i get it i am converting it to blob and generating a temporary src for this using 
**URL.createObjectURL(file)**
I know that createObjectURL is not going to work in IE as it is not allowed there.
now the only option i have left with is to use any third party library like pdf.js to make this thing work.i have tried the same and i had some success in it.But as it comes with the big worker.js library i am trying not to use it for just one thing.
can someone please suggest me if is there any other way of achieving this task?
i have following things or questions in my mind.

1. host this pdf online and just return the pdf link to the front end(i am not a bakend developer so i dont know if it is possible to host pdf dynamically somewhere in the same domain or at any third party host)
2. get something equivalent to 'URL.createObjectURL' for explorer and then use object/embed/iframe to show it
3. render the pdf in a page at server side and just return the whole document to front-end.
4. try a heavy library like pdf.js and make it work(last option for me)
5. any other solution which i am not aware of.

thanks in advance for your help.